# "To view this email as a web page, go here."

Tags: marketing-cloud

In marketing cloud > content builder why "To view this email as a web page, go here." showing as a text while i am sending for test mail?

Comment: What do you mean? Please elaborate and include more details because it’s hard to understand what problem you are encountering.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check the option **Enable System Generated Links**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The line "To view this email as a web page, go here." will automatically be added to the Email header when you are using a Marketing Cloud built-in email template and your MC setting is configured with the System Default header.

In case, you want to turn it off then you have 2 options:

1. Use a custom email template (that you built by yourself)
2. Go to the navigations below and turn it off:

Email Studio >> Admin >> Account Settings >> Edit >> HTML Header >> Select "None", save.
Email Studio >> Admin >> Delivery Profiles >> Select your Delivery Profile >> Header >> Select "None", save.